# NSURLRequest problem

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsurlrequest

Hee,

I got a problem with my NSURLRequest HTTP POST and i cannot find out what is going wrong.

This is my server side php:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <?php 
        if (! isset($_POST['sometext'])) {
            echo "NOT SET";
        } else {
            echo $_POST['sometext'];
        }
    ?>
</body></html>
```

This is my Objective c code to post the data:

```
NSString *urlString = @"http://localhost:8888/postpage";
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:urlString];
NSMutableURLRequest *urlRequest=[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

[url release];


    [urlRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [urlRequest addValue: msgLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [urlRequest setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-type"];
    NSString *postString = @"sometext=Hello&language=en";
    NSString *msgLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postString length]];
    [urlRequest setHTTPBody:[postString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];


NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:urlRequest returningResponse:nil error:nil] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"%@",returnString);
```

The result of the NSLog is:

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        NOT SET 
    </body>
</html>
```

Thanks already

Comment: Where are you adding your content length and content type? Does the server check those fields? I can add an answer based on your reply.

Comment: See my edit. But it still does not work.

Comment: Are you sure about the encoding style you are using? Also should it not be urlRequest and not request? Also you need to add it before you set http body. Can you post the code you are actually running?

Comment: urlRequest/request was a typo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I came across the same problem some times, and the solution was to add this to the request:

```
[urlRequest setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-type"];
```

Answer (score 2):

A possible source of the problem may be the fact that in the code you are setting the **Content-Length** header before assigning the value to the **msgLength** variable. Because ob Obj-C methods on the nil object return nil (and nil is 0), you are setting the Content-Lenght to 0. Try Moving the line

```
NSString *msgLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postString length]];
```

before

```
[urlRequest addValue: msgLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you can try [ASIHTTPRequest Library](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) that it not only can easy handle http request like your problem just use [ASIFormDataRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use#sending_a_form_post_with_ASIFormDataRequest), but also easy to asynchronous handle.

Comment: BSD licensed, free to use, non invasive, so can be used in commercial projects without giving up rights to source code.